# why do everything tend to be stable?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, forces, electrons, electronics

Whenever I ask'why does a proton attract electron?'
People say that 'because they are oppositely charged'

But I want to know why do opposite Charges attract each other and tend to become neutralised?

The same is for all forces like gravity, intermolecular forces e.t.c.
Is it because nature defined it to be so and just another question that no one can answer.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80807/why-do-same-opposite-electric-charges-repel-attract-each-other-respectively

Comment: @dushyanth are you asking why do there exist attraction forces, why objects placed in a field tend to reach stable equilibrium?

Comment: Invoking the wise Feynman https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Feynman said that forces are basic laws of the nature, and we have to take them as basic axioms. But there is one more question here, why do objects tend to stable equilibrium.