# Like charges and unlike charges

Tags: electrostatics, quantum-spin, coulombs-law

Like charges repel and unlike charges attract. But when do like charges attract and unlike charges repel?Please cite an example to justify it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Could you give some more details about your question. Maybe related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80807/why-do-same-opposite-electric-charges-repel-attract-each-other-respectively or https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185326/why-do-like-charges-repel-and-opposite-charges-attract

Comment: Well I am asking is there a possibility that like charges attract each other and unlike charges repel each other ?

Comment: They repel if they are intermediated with spin0 or spin2 particles. Electric charge is intermediated with photons, they are spin1.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can write a tricky answer and say that if I have two electron loops, each loop will act as a separate magnet and if I'm able to orient the loops properly such that the north pole faces the north pole, I may have repulsion between the two systems.

This is possible only if we disregard the coulumb's attraction which is always greater than magnetic field that can be produced by such a setup.

But there has been an experiment in which such a phenomenon was observed where negatively charged entity seemed to attract another negatively charged entity to form a stable product. A model was used to explain this and this model explained it without violating Coulumb's law. Link below if you're interested in reading more about it.

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpclett.6b00981