# Can two charges with same sign atrract?

Tags: electrostatics

Can two  charges with same sign (++/--)  separated by some finite distance attract each other ?

Comment: Theoretically if one of the charges is massive enough, the force of gravity could exceed the repulsive EM force.  I know of no such particle however with a suitable charge to mass ratio.

Comment: What does the Coulomb force law tell you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do same/opposite electric charges repel/attract each other, respectively?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80807/)

Comment: While not immediately obvious that the proposed duplicate is a duplicate, the question of like-charge repulsion/attraction is queried and discussed.

Comment: Electrons in a superconductor can attract each other ...

Answer (score 9):

If you are talking about point charges then, as explained above, the answer is no.

But in the case of non-uniform charge distributions, it is possible for same-charge particles to attract, if they are sufficiently close.

As an example, the following two particles are identical, each having a net charge of -1. Plotted below them is their potential energy as a function of distance. As you can see, when far away they repel each other like ordinary point charges. But when sufficiently close, they attract.

[image]

These dipole-dipole interactions are important in many areas of physics and chemistry.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the terminology on $\pm$ for the charges is nothing but a convention to distinguish between the way they move once they feel the electromagnetic field. In fact in nature you almost never measure the charge of a particle but you rather measure the direction it moves between two points at a different potential.

Coming to your question: take two any charges and place them one in front of another. If they attract, then you *define* the two charges to have different signs (no matter which is $+$ and which is $-$). Once you do so, you can take either of the two and test it against another random charge, and so on and so forth. It is **experimentally true** that in the universe exist (so far) only two types of electric charges, and you can assign each charge to one of the two sets $\pm$ using the above technique.

To conclude: the definition of $\pm$ for a charge comes *after* you have tested whether they attract to each other or not.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. At very short range, typically about a femtometer, the strong force becomes dominant, and (as an example) protons can clump together to form atomic nuclei. Of course, for any larger distance the answer is no.

Comment: I believe the user was asking about the electromagnetic interaction instead. Otherwise of course, any other interaction can occur in whatever possible way.